# check value of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have structure like this. On button click jquery code make border of input red if field is empty. Everything works fine with first row. At others row border become red after button click even if i put valid value.

```js
$('.btn-submit').click(function(){
  var value = $(':input').val();
  if(!value.length) {
    $(this).parents('.row').find(':input').css('border-color','#f00');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
  <input>
  <button class='btn-submit'>Check</button>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <input>
  <button class='btn-submit'>Check</button>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <input>
  <button class='btn-submit'>Check</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When any button is clicked, it is checking the value of the **first** `<input>`.

Change this line:

```
var value = $(':input').val();
```

To this:

```
var value = $(this).prev(":input").val();
```

This should select the `<input>` element directly before the button.

---

*Another tip*: You seem to try to find the *child* input of the *parent* using jQuery. Instead, you can find the *sibling*, using something like [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) (which will work in your case).

Comment: @BogdanTushevskyi You're welcome! I'm glad I helped!

Answer (score 1):

Change you JS-Code:

```
$('.btn-submit').click(function(){
    var value = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
    if(!value.length) {
        $(this).parents('.row').find(':input').css('border-color','#f00');
    }
});
```

**Your Issue:**

You select all `<inputs/>` instead of the closest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('.btn-submit').click(function(){
        var value = $(this).parent().find("input").val();
        if(!value.length) {
            $(this).parent().find(':input').css('border-color','#f00');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
 <input>
 <button class='btn-submit'></button>
</div>
<div class='row'>
 <input>
 <button class='btn-submit'></button>
</div>
<div class='row'>
 <input>
 <button class='btn-submit'></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are looking at all the inputs not just the sibling of the button.
Try this javascript instead:

```
$('.btn-submit').click(function(){
    var value = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
    if(!value.length) {
        $(this).parents('.row').find(':input').css('border-color','#f00');
    }
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maneeshchiba/9q20e9ca/8/)